# Действие в конце любого запроса Web API ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

Мне нужно выполнять действие в конце каждого запроса. Я не знаю, откуда прилетит запрос (много точек входа). У меня зарегистрирован DependencyInjection *AddScoped* (в начало запроса я попадаю), как сделать аналогично в конце?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать [мидлварю (middleware)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/). Просто найдите правильное место в вашей цепочке обработчиков запросов, и допишите туда всё что нужно:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // в этой строчке можно выполнить любые действия в начале каждого запроса
    try { await next(context); }
    finally
    {
        // в этой точке можно выполнить любые действия в конце каждого запроса
    }
});
```

При желании этот код можно вынести в отдельный класс, также это поможет мидлваре иметь свои зависимости:

```cs
public class MyImportantMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyImportantMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, …)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, …)
    {
        // в этой строчке можно выполнить любые действия в начале каждого запроса
        try { await _next(context); }
        finally
        {
            // в этой точке можно выполнить любые действия в конце каждого запроса
        }
    }
}
```

При этом зависимости можно принимать либо в конструктор (такие зависимости обязаны быть синглтонами либо зависящими от них transient), либо прямо в метод InvokeAsync. Использовать такую мидлварю можно через метод `.UseMiddleware<MyImportantMiddleware>()`.

Если вам нужно выполнять некоторые действия не для любого запроса, а только для группы "избранных" (или напротив, нужно исключить некоторую группу) - можете использовать метаданные конечной точки. Для этого нужно, во-первых, поставить вашу мидлварю после UseRouting - а во-вторых, использовать `context.GetEndpoint();` для получения конечной точки и свойство `Metadata` для извлечения метаданных. Сами метаданные в конечную точку можно добавить при помощи атрибутов (любой атрибут метода становится метаданными).

---

Если уж вы заговорили о внедрении scoped-зависимостей, то да, таким образом тоже можно выполнять действия в каждом запросе. Однако, такие действия выполняются отнюдь не в начале каждого запроса, а только когда обработчику запроса понадобится ваша зависимость. С другой стороны, таким образом вы можете отловить запросы, не являющиеся HTTP-запросами.

В любом случае, если вас устраивает такой способ - для выполнения действий в конце обработки запроса вы можете использовать интерфейс IDisposable и его метод Dispose.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!